# ng --version muestra <error> para npm

Tags: angular, npm

Cuando quiero ver la información de la versión de mi paquete angular, obtengo un `<error>` en la versión del Package Manager:

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 17.2.0
Node: 20.11.1
Package Manager: npm <error>
OS: win32 x64

Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1702.0 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         17.2.0 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   17.2.0 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          17.2.0 (cli-only)
```

¿Alguna idea de cómo corregir el error?

Comment: Perdón, olvidé comentarlo, mi instalación está en Windows

Comment: ¿Que versión de npm te bota bro? npm -v

Comment: La versión de npm es la 10.2.4